# Swift How to solve a Memory "Leak"

Tags: ios, swift, caching, memory-leaks

I have encountered a memory "leak" that I don't understand.  I have a caching class whose purpose is to limit the number of instances of heavy Data items.  Even when it stores *NO* instances of those items, they are being retained somehow.  If they are from a background thread, I believe they are released upon completion of the task.  But, of course, as demonstrated by the code, on the main thread they persist.

This occurs on iPadOS 14.8, iPadOS 15 and MacCatalyst.

What am I missing or don't understand?

```
class DataCache {
    var id: String
    var data: Data? {
        get {
            let url = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                .appendingPathComponent("\(id).txt")
            return try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        }
        
        set {
            let url = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                .appendingPathComponent("\(id).txt")
            try! newValue!.write(to: url)
        }
    }

    init(id: String, data: Data) {
        self.id = id
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

```
class Item  {
    static var selection = [Item]()
    static var items = [String:Item]()
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var itemData: DataCache
    
    init() {
        itemData = DataCache(id: id,
                            data: Data(String(repeating: "dummy", count: 4_000_000).utf8)
                            )
    }
    
    required init(_ other: Item) {
        self.itemData = DataCache(id: self.id, data: other.itemData.data!)
    }
    
    func duplicate(times: Int) {
        for index in 0..<times {
            print(index)
            Item.selection.append(Item(self))
        }
    }
    
}

@main struct Main {
    static func main() throws {
        let item = Item()
        
        perform(item)
        
        performOnSelection() { item in
            let _ = Item(item)
        }
        
        while (true) {}
    }
    
    static func perform(_ item: Item) {
        item.duplicate(times: 100)
    }
    
    static func performOnSelection(perform action: @escaping (Item)->Void) {
        var done = false
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            for item in Item.selection {
                action(item)
            }
            done = true
        }
        
        while !done { sleep (1) }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check with the Memory graph tool from Xcode to see who's keeping references to the "leaked" objects.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but there’s no point in dispatching to a global queue if you’re only going to block the calling thread until `done` is set to true. (And, btw, the updating of `done` is not thread-safe.)

Comment: This is just a minimal, reproducible example.  It actually comes from a SwiftUI app where the done and wait is unnecessary.  Here I just added them to allow time to examine the results. I left the global queue in to show that the items were being released, so not really a leak.  But thanks for the comment and the quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have autorelease objects being created. Insert an `autoreleasepool` to drain the pool periodically, e.g.:

```swift
func performOnSelection(perform action: @escaping (Item) -> Void) {
    ...

    autoreleasepool {
        perform(item)
    }

    performOnSelection() { item in
        autoreleasepool {
            let _ = Item(item)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and

```swift
func duplicate(times: Int) {
    for index in 0..<times {
        print(index)
        autoreleasepool { [self] in
            Item.selection.append(Item(self))
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. without `autoreleasepool`:

[image]

And with:

[image]

It turns off to be much faster when it is not dealing with all of those lingering autorelease objects, too. And peak memory usage has gone from 3.4gb to 47mb.

Comment: Awesome!  It works like a charm!  I vaguely remember these from Objective-C.  Didn't know they were available for Swift.

Comment: Generally we don’t have to worry about it in Swift code, but you’re using Swift Foundation types that bridge to legacy Objective-C API behind the scenes. Whenever you see memory not getting released in long loops, autorelease objects are a common culprit.